# req.param undefined because OriginalUrl in Express/Sails not accepting Orientdb @rid

Tags: express, sails.js, orientdb

I am very new to this all so this could just be my inability to code. I am trying to pass a request to a controller using href.

```
href="/user/edit/<%= user.id %>"
href="/user/edit/#12:0"
```

where user id is from an Orientdb database. An example of the format of @rid is #12:0

when I output the request to the console I can see that I am only getting "user/edit" as the OriginalUrl. It seems to not like the # and : symbols. Is this the expected behaviour or is there something else amiss?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about node.js, but probably this is caused by the `#` symbol, which is a special symbol in an URL ([fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)). Using the REST API you should not use the hash character, see [documentation](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/OrientDB-REST.html#document)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. it didn't work but it put me on the right track to solving the question. so thank you.

Comment: See documentation, http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/OrientDB-REST.html#document. Using the REST API you should not use the hash character

Comment: Yep the problem wasn't the connection to Orientdb it was the internal routes of sailsjs and nodejs that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to entirely solve but got a workaround which I am happy with for now. It involved doing the following.

```
href="/user/edit/<%= user.id.substring(1) %>"
```

This just deletes the first character in the string. I then add the hash later when I need to search for things via user.id